# Php: how to remove phone numbers from string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove / detect phone numbers from messages between users of my marketplace website (think eBay does something similar)
this is the code I'm using:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]+)/', '', $string);
```

BUT... it's too aggressive and it does strip away any number with 2 or more numerals... how can set a limit of say 7 numbers instead?

to be more precise the phone numbers can be any format like

```
3747657654
374-7657654
374-765-7654
(374)765-7654
etc...(i cannot predict what the users will write depending of their habits)
```

Comment: Without some idea of the string you are trying to detect phone number in we cannot be a lot of help. Add a sample(s) to your question

Comment: any phone number in the world written by a human: either a sequence of 7 or more numbers, in all possible way a phone is formatted in the western countries. i can't predict what the users will write

Comment: `i cannot predict what the users will write depending of their habits` How will you figure out difference between 7 digit phone# and 7 digit money e.g. `1234567`?

Comment: Before you can write code to detect phone numbers, you have to explain in English how you define a phone number.  Giving examples isn't an English definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression :

`/([0-9]+[\- ]?[0-9]{6,})/`

changed to match your samples:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zF3wL9/1)

Comment: yes it does BUT also ti does remove any number like a time stamp eg. "hey I will see you there from 4pm to 8 my cell is 3747657654"

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the exact requirements as now you have 1 or more numbers followed by an optional `-` or space followed by 1 or more numbers again.

If you wanted for example at least 2 numbers before the space or `-` followed by at least 5 numbers, you could use something like:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]{2,}[\- ]?[0-9]{5,})/', '', $string);
                                              ^^^^ Here you can specify mininimum / maximum
                               ^^^^ Here you can specify mininimum / maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<![0-9]|[0-9]-)[0-9](?:[- ]?[0-9]){6}(?!-?[0-9])/', '', $string);
```

The lookarounds are here to avoid numbers with more than 7 digits, but if you want something more specific, you should provide an example string.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to determine whether a number of X digits (where X is a valid phone number length) is a phone number or something else without some sort of context intelligence happening. A simple regex can't determine the difference between *"call me at 3453456"* and *"call me when you've flown 3453456 miles"*.

Therefore trying to catch phone numbers without any formatting (just straight digits) with a regex is hopeless, pure and simple. Attempting to do so is only holding you back from finding a regex that can find formatted/semi-formatted numbers. What you should be going for here is *"get the obvious and as many others as possible with minimal false positives...but recognize I can't get them all."*

For that I'd recommend this:

`/1?[ \-]?\(?([0-9]{3})?\)?[ \-]?([0-9]{3})[ \-]([0-9]{4})/g`

It should not get the first three, but get all the rest in this list:

```
no-match: 3747657654
no-match: 444444444444444
no-match: 7657654
match:    374-765-7654
match:    1-374-765-7654
match:    (374)765-7654
match:    (374) 765 7654
match:    765-7654
match:    1 (374) 765 7654
match:    1(374)765 7654
```